# Yii2-Grid view showing wrong count of items

Tags: php, gridview, pagination, yii2

I have `grid view` in which there are 8 items. But the count is displaying `Showing 1-8 of 10 items.`

[image]

**Controller code**

```
public function actionViewsetpdf($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    $sqla = $session->get('result');

    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    $cnt = $session->get('count');

    $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
        'sql' => $sqla,
        'totalCount'=>$cnt,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 20,
        ],
    ]);

    return $this->render('viewsetpdf', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        'id' => $model->id
        /*'searchModel' => $searchModel*/
    ]);


}
```

**View Code**

```
 <?= GridView::widget([
         'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
          /*'filterModel' => $searchModel,*/


       'columns' => [

           ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
           [
               'label'=>'OGP Serial #',
               'value' => 'OGP_Serial_No'
           ],

           'Date',
           'Created_By',
           'Meter_Serial_Number',
           'Issued_To',
           'Store',
           'Admin_Incharge',
           'Project_Manager',
           'Driver_Name',
 ],
]); ?>
```

I have checked my `count` query and `result` query and both are returning me the correct count and result i.e. 8 items. I don't know why the summary is not displaying correctly.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you add your SQL to the question? Most likely `$session->get('count');` is returning `10` but since we can't see where that comes from, there is no way of telling what's causing it. Also, on the `$this->render(...)` you shouldn't be using `$this->findModel(id)` since you already have the model on `$model`, it will be cheaper to use that.

Comment: SqlDataProvider::$sql should be a query string, and SqlDataProvider::totalCount an integer. Is that your case? _result_ in your session doesn't sound like a query... What and when do you save those values into the session?

Comment: Use ActiveDataProvider and send the query. Count will be handled by the grid view by using method from ActiveDataProvider itself.